# Can't Format USB stick after DISKPART

Tags: usb, format, diskpart

Win 7 Pro on HP6250 x64
I used the steps under getting rid of a hidden partition on a USB drive. That worked but now I can't FORMAT the stick. The last version I tried was FORMAT FS=FAT . The normal disk management utility completes without displaying any error messages, but it hasn't done anything. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there are any partitions on the disk at this point? A screenshot of the drive in Disk Management can help with that. Be sure to crop out any other drives if you don't want to show them to us.

To get to Disk Management, click the Start menu, and type "Disk management". This will give you an entry stating "Create and format hard disk partitions". From there, you click the USB disk, and it will show you whether there are partitions or unallocated space.

Comment: No, the partitions were gone. I tried elsewhere and came across an item that suggested STORAGE under Disk Management after very little fooling around I got it formatted. The bad news that it was assigned a new drive letter. I don't really care. So the issue is resolved. Joshua Nurczyk .